# Show that the following function is continuous on R^2

Tags: continuity, matrix-norms

Consider the function f : $\displaystyle\mathbb{R^2}→ \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}
\frac{sin(|x_2|)cot(|x_1|)+cos(|x_2|)}{sin(|x_2|)-cot(|x_1|)cos(|x_2|)}(|x_1|+|x_2|)^{-1},  & \text{if $(x_1,x_2)\neq(0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$}
\end{cases}$$
Is the function continuous on $\displaystyle\mathbb{R^2}$?
$$$$
I tried to rewrite the function $f(x_1,x_2)$ as a function only depending on a norm of $(x_1,x_2)$, and I also tried to show if it is continuous by using a sequence $x_k=(\frac{1}{k},\frac{1}{k})$, which converges to 0, and replace it to $f(x_1,x_2)$ but still I can't get anywhere with that and to be honest I don't know how to continue anymore. Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the substitution $x=|x_1|+|x_2|$. The fraction of the trigonometric functions on the left side simplifies drastically if you replace the cotagent by a fraction of sine and cosine, and then use the addition theorems. In the end you get $-\tan(x)/x$. This converges to $-1$.

Comment: Could you please show me the first steps of the replacement, because I am not understanding it very well. Thanks!!

Comment: @Techlover multiply the top and bottom of your large fraction by $\sin|x_1|$, remembering that $\cot\theta=\cos\theta/\sin\theta$. The problem then simplifies as noted above.

Comment: And in the end, after all steps, what does it mean that it converges at -1?

Comment: Does it mean that when x1 and x2 goes to 0 our function converges to -1, but in the exercise above shows that when x1 and x2 are 0 the function is 0, so the function is not continuous in R^2?

Comment: Yes, it means this.